# file_put_contents does not work properly in cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a cron job running **every 1 minute** to send push messages to mobile phones.

1.I perform fetch query in database to get all messages that I need to send

2.With the data in that array I perform another fetch query. **I use file_put_contents to write data to some file**.

3.Then I send push messages using some services.

**Message is successfully received but data is not written in file**(that I do in second point).

**Note: This code runs perfectly when I manually run this file  on my local machine.**

**What I found**

Someone suggested me that your mysql is performing queries slow and so other lines of scripts are executed before and so the error.

The Code

```
    Sone database query that will give customer ids in $customer_ids array

    $customer_ids = array_unique($customer_ids);
    foreach ($customer_ids as $customer_id){
        //Problem is here.file is written here using file_put_contents (this does not work-file does not update)
        PushMessage_Model_Mapper_PushMessage::getPublishfile($customer_id);
    }
    foreach ($customer_ids as $customer_id){
        //push messages are send by calling some function
    }
```

Are there any known issues for such behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that the user under which the cronjob is executed can write to the file.

Comment: yes, it has all the permissions. we tried logging dummy data to file through cron job.

Comment: log the output of the cronjob in a file, maybe the script throws errors